# WooCommerce get Shipping Class of product from either the product id or the order after order is completed

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have been trying to figure out how to get the shipping class from the order after payment is complete. I have found this...

```
$shipping_class = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class();
```

but that retrieves the shipping class from an active cart, I need to get this after the order is processed, possibly from...

```
$order = new wc_get_order(id);
$items = $order->get_items();
```

I can then get the product and variation ids but for some reason I am not seeing how to get the shipping class from this.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Palm to FACE!!!

using the product id...

<strike>$_product = get_product(id);</strike>

```
$_product = wc_get_product()

$shipclass = $_product->get_shipping_class();
```

this returns the products shipping class.

EDIT: as mentioned by Aniruddha get_product is depreciated answer has been updated.

Comment: `get_product()` function is deprecated. use `wc_get_product()` instead.

Comment: Doh yes correct, double palm Saturday. Thank you for that!!!

Comment: what about for product variations -- if you need to get the shipping_class foreach individual product variation